# custom menu links

Tags: 7, theming

I have a modal that I need to attach to a menu link in D7. I tried to go put the name of the modal into the menu path #myModal4 but it tells me The path '#myModal4' is either invalid or you do not have access to it. Is there a way to add custom link?

Comment: What is the link meant to do?

Comment: You can add a valid path in a menu's path.

Comment: Well what I want to do is have a modal where they click on a menu item and this modal pops up with a message. But inorder to do that I have to be able to put the modal id into a menu item path. So for instance my modal has a ID of #myModal4 so I need to be able to put that into the menu item path so it will trigger the modal when clicked.